# java - NullPointerException when using arrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am writing a `JSF 2.2` project on `Eclipse Neon`. I have two arraylists; one is fetched from group of checkboxes that are checked by the user(`arrayList1`) and the other one is fetched from keywords that are entered into chips component(`arrayList2`) by user inside `.xhtml` page. What I need to do is I have to combine those two arraylists.

The problem is when I leave `chips` empty, `arraylist2` returns `null` while `arraylist1` returns empty string when I leave the boxes unchecked as well. So I think the problem is related to else `if (lengthlist1 > 0 && arrayList2.size() == 0)` part because all the other cases functioning well. If check the checkboxes and leave the `chips` component empty and then run the code, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Again, all the other if - else statements are working fine.

I basically have 4 cases:

```
    private String wordx;
    private List<String> arrayList1;
    private List<String> arrayList2;

    public void arrayList2List() {

            arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public void concatenate() throws IOException {

                int lengthlist1 = arrayList1.size();
                int lengthlist2 = arrayList2.size();

                ArrayList<String> concat = null;

                if (lengthlist2 > 0 && lengthlist1 > 0) {
                    concat = new ArrayList<>(lengthlist1 + lengthlist2);

                    for (int i = 0; i < lengthlist1; i++) {
                        concat.add(arrayList1.get(i) + And + wordx);

                        for (int l = 0; l < lengthlist2; l++) {
                            concat.add(arrayList2.get(l) + And + wordx);
                        }
                    }   
                } else if (lengthlist1 > 0 && arrayList2.size() == 0) { /* I think problem occurs here, when I leave checkboxes list empty */
                    concat = new ArrayList<>(lengthlist1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < lengthlist1; k++) {
                        concat.add(arrayList1.get(k) + And + wordx);
                    }

                } else if (lengthlist1 <= 0 && lengthlist2 > 0) {
                    concat = new ArrayList<>(lengthlist2);
                    for (int m = 0; m < lengthlist2; m++) {
                        concat.add(arrayList2.get(m) + And + wordx);
                    }

                } else {
                    TODO:do something else
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < concat.size(); j++) {
                    Search(concat.get(j));
                }

            }
```

Can someone explain the root cause of the error? Where do I go wrong? All help will be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't initialized arrayList1 ... please correct it

Comment: I already have it. I just didn't write it there because it is not the reason for the error.

Comment: I have solved it; I have changed `int lengthlist2 = arrayList2.size();` with `int lengthlist2 = 0;` and added the following code piece: `if(arrayList2 == null){
   lengthlist2 = 0 ;
  }
  else{
   lengthlist2 = Arraylist2.size();
  }`